# Codeigniter issue - remove trailing slashes, redirect other non-permitted URI characters to a 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have recently added the following to .htaccess to remove trailing slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

I also extend CI_URI to remove non-permitted URI chars and redirect to a 404 page (thankyou to whoever was the original author, not me!):

```
public function _filter_uri($str)
{
if ($str != '' && $this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars') != '' && $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
{
// preg_quote() in PHP 5.3 escapes -, so the str_replace() and addition of - to   preg_quote() is to maintain backwards
// compatibility as many are unaware of how characters in the permitted_uri_chars will be parsed as a regex pattern
if ( ! preg_match('|^['.str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-')).']+$|i', $str))
{
show_404(); //show 404 error page instead "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" error
}
}

// Convert programatic characters to entities and return
return str_replace(
array('$',     '(',     ')',     '%28',   '%29'),
// Bad
array('&#36;', '&#40;', '&#41;', '&#40;', '&#41;'),
// Good
$str);
}
}
```

Since I added the .htaccess code, any disallowed characters in the URI e.g. http://www.mysite.com/contro,ller/func,tion (with commas) result in a redirect to a 301 page, with a subsequent link to a 404 error page (i.e. "The page has moved here" with a link to my standard 404 page).

Can I get both to work together, so disallowed chars are just redirected to my standard 404 page?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to remove trailing slash?

Comment: To prevent duplicate content issues - SEO. It means there will only be one version of each page indexed

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the list of `item('permitted_uri_chars')` you can probably duplicate them into a rewrite rule. Say the permitted characters are slashes, numbers/letters, underscores, periods, and hyphens:

```
RewriteRule !^[A-Za-z0-9_/\-\.]*$ - [L,R=404]
```

Also note that URL escaped characters get decoded before being sent through mod_rewrite. So if the URL looks like `http://something.com/foo%20bar`, the expression you use to match against it is: `^foo\ bar$` because the `%20` gets unescaped into a space.

Comment: Thankyou a good answer, unfortunately I'm also trying to keep my custom error page which is uses the codeigniter library, rather than writing a separately written html page. This is to preserve access to the site menus. Is there a way to route the 404 error from .htaccess in such a way?

Comment: Perhaps I can use routes.php to redirect all trailing slashes rather than .htaccess?

Comment: @GregoryLawton If you need to use a code igniter page, you'll have to go through code igniter to do it. There's probably a way to use the rule to redirect to a codeigniter page that returns a 404.